# Searching for data in a Header

Tags: python

I currently have a script that reads in data from a file `orderedfile.txt` which has a header layout and data layout as shown below. I now want a python script to search the header file for the parameters a,b,c and the fine fft grid parameters (25,300,300 in this case).

The header file could change slightly in layout and therefore I think it is best not to approach this problem considering the position of each. Instead I think the best way of approaching this would be to search for the phrase "a = " in the header and then setting what is after this equal to a... I cannot figure out how to implement this however. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
BEGIN header

       Real Lattice(A)               Lattice parameters(A)    Cell Angles
   2.4675850   0.0000000   0.0000000     a =    2.467585  alpha =   90.000000
   0.0000000  30.0000000   0.0000000     b =   30.000000  beta  =   90.000000
   0.0000000   0.0000000  30.0000000     c =   30.000000  gamma =   90.000000

 1                            ! nspins
25   300   300                ! fine FFT grid along <a,b,c>
END header: data is "<a b c> pot" in units of Hartrees

 1     1     1            0.042580
 1     1     2            0.049331
 1     1     3            0.038605
 1     1     4            0.049181
```

Comment: When you say positioning may change, do you just mean spacing/line count? Will all these values be in the same order though?

Comment: Yes exactly, the order shall stay consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the file format change it to something more machine readable (e. g. JSON). If you cannot and you are expecting unnotified changes to the format do a strict check for the format, otherwise you could easily misinterpret the file.

For strict checking of such formats I often use regex in a very lazy (but readable) way.

```
import re

def parse_header(f):
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'BEGIN header', l)
    assert m, l
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'', l)
    assert m, l
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'       Real Lattice\(A\)               Lattice parameters\(A\)    Cell Angles', l)
    assert m, l
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'.*a = +(?P<a>[0-9.+-]+) +.*', l)
    assert m, l
    a = float(m.group('a'))
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'.*b = +(?P<b>[0-9.+-]+) +.*', l)
    assert m, l
    b = float(m.group('b'))
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'.*c = +(?P<c>[0-9.+-]+) +.*', l)
    assert m, l
    c = float(m.group('c'))
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'', l)
    assert m, l
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'.*nspins.*', l)
    assert m, l
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'.*(?P<ffta>[0-9]+) +(?P<fftb>[0-9]+) +(?P<fftc>[0-9]+) +! fine FFT grid along <a,b,c>', l)
    assert m, l
    ffta = int(m.group('ffta'))
    fftb = int(m.group('fftb'))
    fftc = int(m.group('fftc'))
    l=next(f)
    m = re.match(r'END header: data is "<a b c> pot" in units of Hartrees', l)
    assert m, l
    l=next(f)
    return a,b,c,ffta,fftb,fftc

# prepare a test 'file'
s = '''BEGIN header

       Real Lattice(A)               Lattice parameters(A)    Cell Angles
   2.4675850   0.0000000   0.0000000     a =    2.467585  alpha =   90.000000
   0.0000000  30.0000000   0.0000000     b =   30.000000  beta  =   90.000000
   0.0000000   0.0000000  30.0000000     c =   30.000000  gamma =   90.000000

 1                            ! nspins
25   300   300                ! fine FFT grid along <a,b,c>
END header: data is "<a b c> pot" in units of Hartrees

 1     1     1            0.042580
 1     1     2            0.049331
 1     1     3            0.038605
 1     1     4            0.049181'''

# file like iterable
f=iter(s.split("\n"))


a,b,c,ffta,fftb,fftc = parse_header(f)
# continue with the file and handle remaining data lines
for line in f:
    print(line)
```